# Opposes in one localhost port ,, any Solution

Tags: ruby, sinatra

i'm using sinatra to work with ruby , when i am run the file in the terminal the normal port for sinatra is "4567" , but for three days ago the terminal print this

```
     Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
     [2014-09-06 00:15:16] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=770 port=4567
```

also the webrick port is "4567"

Comment: And that's not ok because?

Comment: because i've to run sinatra in port "4567" to see my file , but i's take me to the webrick , i don't want to go to webrick i want to run sinatra

Comment: Is there an error? Or is it that you don't understand how ports work? Two apps can't exist on the same port. Sinatra will use Mongrel, Thin or Webrick as its server, depending on what are installed, but you can use `-s` to point it a particular direction. It's difficult to tell what you're asking so you need to add more information and a better description so we can help you.

Comment: i'm so sorry i can't speak english will , but you can see the massage that's it again : Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
     [2014-09-06 00:15:16] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=770 port=4567  ,,

Comment: Which server software do you want Sinatra to use to respond to your http requests on port 4567?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes, we see the message, and we see that there's nothing wrong with it because that's what should be displayed. What problem do you see that you haven't told us about? Did you upgrade/downgrade your gems and are now seeing different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand the problem you're seeing. Maybe this will help:

If I create a simple test server containing the sample Sinatra code:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

And save that to my Desktop as test.rb, I can run Sinatra using:

```
ruby test.rb
```

Sinatra tells me:

```
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

If I uninstall Thin:

```
gem uninstall thin
Remove executables:
  thin

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  y
Removing thin
Successfully uninstalled thin-1.6.2
```

And run the code again:

```
ruby test.rb
[2014-09-05 14:41:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-09-05 14:41:23] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-09-05 14:41:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=26786 port=4567
```

In either case, the code does what it's supposed to. I can connect using curl and get "Hello World!" back:

```
curl http://localhost:4567/hi
Hello World!
```

Sinatra uses Webrick by default, but will pick other servers over it:

```
gem install puma
Fetching: puma-2.9.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed puma-2.9.1
Parsing documentation for puma-2.9.1
Installing ri documentation for puma-2.9.1
Done installing documentation for puma after 3 seconds
1 gem installed

ruby test.rb
Puma 2.9.1 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:4567
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Puma

gem install thin
Fetching: thin-1.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed thin-1.6.2
Parsing documentation for thin-1.6.2
Installing ri documentation for thin-1.6.2
Done installing documentation for thin after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

ruby test.rb
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop

curl http://localhost:4567/hi
Hello World!
```

Use `-s` to control which server Sinatra uses:

```
ruby test.rb -s puma
Puma 2.9.1 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:4567
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Puma
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sinatra Docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html):

> **:run** - enable/disable the built-in web server Boolean specifying
>   whether the built-in web server is started after the app is fully
>   loaded. By default, this setting is enabled only when the :app_file
>   matches $0, i.e. when running a Sinatra app file directly with ruby
>   myapp.rb. To disable the built-in web server:
>
> ```
> set :run, false
> ```
>
> **:server** - handler used for built-in web server. String
>   or Array of Rack server handler names. When the :run setting is
>   enabled, Sinatra will run through the list and start a server with the
>   first available handler. The :server setting is set as follows by
>   default:
>
> ```
> set :server, %w[thin mongrel webrick]
> ```

[Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html):

> Sinatra is a DSL for quickly creating web applications in Ruby with minimal effort:

```
# myapp.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
Install the gem:

gem install sinatra
And run with:

ruby myapp.rb
View at: http://localhost:4567
```

> It is recommended to also run `gem install thin`, which Sinatra will pick up if available.

By default, Sinatra first looks to see if you have the Thin server software installed--if yes, Sinatra uses Thin to respond to requests on port 4567.  If you do not have Thin installed, next Sinatra checks if you have the Mongrel server software installed, and Sinatra uses Mongrel if it is installed, and finally Sinatra uses the always available Webrick server software, which comes with ruby.

The message you are seeing is Sinatra telling you which server software it is using to respond to requests on port 4567.